# how to write this code with cakephp 1.3 html helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i try to use gallery prettyphoto but i have problem with this code..how to write this code with cakephp html helper

```
<li><a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

The key part is to turn off HTML escaping for the link text (as it contains an HTML image tag). Also, images are usually stored in the paths like `/img/...` but that will depend on your implementation.

```
<li><?php
$thumb = $this->Html->image('images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg', array(
    'width' => 60,
    'height' => 60,
    'alt' => 'Nice building',
));
echo $this->Html->link($thumb, 'images/fullscreen/2.jpg', array(
    'rel' => 'prettyPhoto[gallery1]',
    'escape' => false, // important
));
?></li>
```